# Search entire column for string, return all row values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Trying to to write a script to search through column A starting at the top, and return all values of the row on which it matches a string. I want to have it output the values in plain html, while the string would be defined from a parameter on the url line.

```
function doGet(e) {

var param = e.parameter.param;
var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEETID").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var column = sheet.getRange("A");
  var values = column.getValues(); 
  var row = 0;

  while ( values[row] && values[row][0] !== param ) {
    row++;
}

  if (values[row][0] === param) 
   var output = row.getValues()
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(output);

}
```

Other errors as well while changing code...
Range not found (line 5, file "Code", project "Column Search")

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately You cannot retrieve a range as `getRange("A")`

### You cannot modify your code to

```
  var column = sheet.getRange("A:A");
```

> However keep in mind that this will make your code very slow. Consider
>   retrieving only the range that actually has contents:

```
var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow();
var column = sheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,1);
```

References:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

Comment: Great suggestion, I appreciate that! Its true that having the range defined beforehand would be quicker when the code runs. I still cannot seem to get it running for some reason.. I am getting this error: 'TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined.'